# FreeRTOS Task should not return - ESP32

Tags: c++, multithreading, esp32, freertos

I'm using multi-threading on my ESP32. I have created two tasks and pinned them to core 1. With one of them, I get the following error:

```
E (20426) FreeRTOS: FreeRTOS Task "MeasurementTask" should not return, Aborting now!
abort() was called at PC 0x4008b8f3 on core 1

Backtrace: 0x4008f34c:0x3ffd0a40 0x4008f57d:0x3ffd0a60 0x4008b8f3:0x3ffd0a80

Rebooting...
```

However, there is no `return` statement in my "MeasurementTask" (see code below). What's the issue here?

`tracker.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "tracker.h"

void threadedLoop(void *pvParameters) {
  Serial.println("Loop task pinned");
  for(;;) {
    checkAPTrigger();
    mqttLoop();
  }
}

void setupTracker() {
  Serial.print("Setup start: ");
  Serial.println(millis());
  Wire.begin();
  setup_sensors();
  if(setupAP()) {
    setupTime();
    setupMQTT();
  }
  Serial.print("Setup done: ");
  Serial.println(millis());

  Serial.println("Pinning measurement");
  TaskHandle_t measureTask;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    takeMeasurement,
    "MeasurementTask",
    2048,
    NULL,
    1,
    NULL,
    ARDUINO_RUNNING_CORE
  );

  Serial.println("Pinning loop");
  TaskHandle_t loopTask;
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
    threadedLoop,
    "LoopTask",
    2048,
    NULL,
    1,
    NULL,
    ARDUINO_RUNNING_CORE
  );
}

void loopTracker() {
  //takeMeasurement();
}

void takeMeasurement(void *pvParameters) {
  Serial.println("Measurement task pinned");
  DynamicJsonDocument root(512);
  JsonObject rootObj = root.to<JsonObject>();
  read_sensors(rootObj);

  if(!(settings.mqttUsed && publishData(rootObj))) {
    appendFile("data", root);
  }

  serializeJsonPretty(root, Serial);
  Serial.println("\n---\n");
}
```

Sketch:

```cpp
#include <tracker.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  wm.resetSettings();
  setupTracker();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  loopTracker();
}
```

There are quite some files included in the `tracker.h`, but I don't believe they're relevant to this problem. Some of the functions used in the `takeMeasurement` do have return values, but I never return them in that function itself.

Comment: Typically "no return" doesn't literally mean a lack of `return` statement, but rather that the control flow of the function never terminates. There should be some sort of infinite while-loop to keep the function running indefinitely.

Comment: Ah, so if I don't want that, I need to delete the task?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual solution should be in this case, I'm just letting you know what the error message means.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I'll try that out then and see if that works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In FreeRTOS, [tasks](https://www.freertos.org/implementing-a-FreeRTOS-task.html) are started with `xTaskCreate...` and ended with `vTaskDelete`. A task function may not simply "end", this is not allowed.

Put `vTaskDelete(NULL);` at the end of the function to gracefully end the task:

```
void takeMeasurement(void *pvParameters) {
  // . . . task code . . .
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Having said that, tasks are usually meant to be long-running. For example, the measurement task could be an endless loop that takes the measurement, sleeps for a while, and repeats.

Comment: Yes, @Patrick Roberts already mentioned this and this was indeed the solution

Comment: Also, I want to make this looping eventually, I just haven't implemented that yet and won't always need it

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that You forgot to add an infinite loop:

```
void takeMeasurement(void *pvParameters) {
    for(;;){ // ** Start of infinite loop **
        Serial.println("Measurement task pinned");
        DynamicJsonDocument root(512);
        JsonObject rootObj = root.to<JsonObject>();
        read_sensors(rootObj);
    
        if(!(settings.mqttUsed && publishData(rootObj))) {
            appendFile("data", root);
        }
    
        serializeJsonPretty(root, Serial);
        Serial.println("\n---\n");
    }   // ** End of infinite loop **
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve it with this :

```
  Void Task1code( void * parameter) {
      for(;;) {
        Code for task 1 - infinite loop
        (...)
      }
    }
```

that come from here : https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-dual-core-arduino-ide/

the for(;;) create a loop inside the task, so the return was never requested ...