# ESP32 FreeRTOS Task should not return

Tags: multithreading, arduino, multitasking, esp32, freertos

I am using multi threading to execute multiple tasks which are available in the queue one by one.
After one task ends, I execute another task but while executing the second task in queue, I am facing error.

```
E (18470) FreeRTOS: FreeRTOS Task "taskTwo" should not return, Aborting now!
```

Here is my code,

```
QueueHandle_t priorityTwoQue;
TaskHandle_t thTwo;

void receiveTaskDataFromSomeFunction() {

  dataholder = (struct DataHolder *)malloc(sizeof(struct DataHolder));
  extractData(jsonBuffer, dataholder);
  jsonBuffer.clear();

  SerialDebug.print("Requst Sending To Que");
  xQueueSend(priorityTwoQue, &dataholder, portMAX_DELAY);

  processQueue();
      
}

void processQueue() {

  delay(100);
  SerialDebug.println("Creating Task Prio 2");
  xTaskCreate(taskPriorityTwo, "TaskTwo", 5000, NULL, 2, &thTwo);

}

void taskPriorityTwo(void * paramter) {

  SerialDebug.println("Task Initiated");
  threadTask(priorityTwoQue, "task2");
  vTaskDelete(thTwo);

}


void threadTask(QueueHandle_t priorityQue, String taskName) {

   struct DataHolder *taskdataholder;
   xQueueReceive(priorityQue, &taskdataholder, portMAX_DELAY);
   SerialDebug.print("Executing Task");
   executeHttpRequest(taskdataholder);   
   requestInProgress = false;
   processQueue();

}
```

In the above code receiveTaskDataFromSomeFunction() is called whenever new task request is received, how ever in my case 4 requests are received one by one with an interval of 1 second. Hence i am putting them into the queue. Each request is executed as an http request which takes 5 seconds to compelete.

This code executes the first request without any issue but on executing the second request i get the error which i have mentioned above.

My question is how can i resolve this issue of executing the tasks which are available in queue one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I think dynamically creating/deleting tasks for this purpose is not the best approach. Why not keeping the task running just processing incoming requests ?
However, better use `vTaskDelete(NULL);` to self-delete a task.
The global task handle might get re-used/overwritten. Also it seems you don‘t really need the task handle. It‘s optional for `xTaskCreate` and you can specify NULL for the handle argument if you‘re not interested in it.
And you should do some error checking ;)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can logically understand your point, can u please explain a bit through out my code.

Answer (score 1):

In the [RTFreeOS manual](https://www.freertos.org/implementing-a-FreeRTOS-task.html) it states that tasks should run in an endless loop, so not terminate, ever. If they do terminate, they will need to be deleted with `vTaskDelete(NULL);`, as mentioned by HS2.

See also this question/answer: [FreeRTOS Task should not return - ESP32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63634917/freertos-task-should-not-return-esp32)